# Using !FindInMap when creating a blockdevice

Tags: aws-cloudformation

So I am just trying to use FindInMap when creating a disk.

I get the structure but I am getting the error:

> "Value of property BlockDeviceMappings must be of type List"

So it is clear I dont fully understand the layout.

Just trying all I can think of.. Unfortunately the examples from AWS mainly reference using it for regions.. Not too helpful as you will see.

```
 ec2Map:                         ---(my map)
    test:                         ----(outter key)
      InstanceType: t2.small
      volsize: 20                ----(inner key)
    dev:
      InstanceType: t2.small
      volsize: 40

Note: there is parameter that references 'myec2instances' so I can pick the size in a drop down.

#here is where I am lost. How to I  reference the other items needed like device name and volumetype? 

So I get rid of the error mentioned above..


 BlockDeviceMappings: !FindInMap
        - ec2Map
        - !Ref 'myec2instance'
        - volsize
           DeviceName: "/dev/sdf"
      #       Ebs:
      #         VolumeSize: 
      #         VolumeType: gpa
```

I'm basically trying to make it so when the test ec2 is provisioned it gets an additional 20gb volume added, for dev it will get a 40gb volume.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to move your `!FindInMap` down in the structure and repeat it, like this:

```yml
BlockDeviceMappings:
  - DeviceName: '/dev/sdf' # additional volume
    Ebs:
      VolumeSize: !FindInMap [ec2Map, !Ref myec2instance, volsize]
      VolumeType: !FindInMap [ec2Map, !Ref myec2instance, voltype]
      ...
```